# hyperlink (anchor) button with background color on IE 8 not working

Tags: html, css

I trying to style background colour of hyperlink button "" and it works fine on Chrome, IE9, Firefox etc except IE 8. After further investigation i found that IE8 does not support css like button:not(.t-button) and it breaks

I wanted to know if i need to add a different css for IE 8 on a different file or i can update the syntax so it does not break for IE 8.

```
button:not(.t-button), .btn, a.btn, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border: none;
    margin: 6px 0 0;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: rgb(64,141,198);
    font-family: 'Arial' ,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em; /* 12 */
    line-height: 2em;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle like http://jsfiddle.net/786wF/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards
Bhavesh

Answer (score 0):

First :not pseudo selector is NOT supported

More info :

- http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/
- http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot

Second, your html is NOT valid, putting div inside anchors

Replace your inner DIV with SPAN

IE will apreciate

Third : jsfiddle does NOT support IE < 8

Answer (score 0):

your code structure is not valid in w3c validator because you put your div inside an  element.try changing your div into other element like span.and do not use the:not pseudo element